# Where can I report error in a localized Steam game description?

Tags: steam

[Russian description](http://store.steampowered.com/app/241910?l=russian) of [Goodbye deponia](http://store.steampowered.com/app/241910) have repeated paragraph in place of translated. Where can i report such errors?

English:

> - A classic point & click adventure in a unique world, in the tradition of Douglas Adams, Terry Pratchett and Matt Groening
> - From the makers of Memoria, Edna & Harvey: The Breakout, A New Beginning and Edna & Harvey: Harvey's New Eyes

Russian:

> - Действие классической приключенческой игры point & click происходит в уникальном мире, созданном в традициях Дугласа Адамса, Терри Пратчетта и Мэтта Грейнинга.
> - Действие классической приключенческой игры point & click происходит в уникальном мире, созданном в традициях Дугласа Адамса, Терри Пратчетта и Мэтта Грейнинга.

Comment: The developers set the English descriptions, though I'm less sure about the translation/localization, but I'd guess contacting the developer rather than Steam would get you farther.

Comment: @BenBrocka You should make that an answer, the devs have access to their games, so changing the localized description of a game shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

**The best way to report errors is by contacting the appropriate [Translation group](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1244344).**

All of Steam is [translated by the community](https://translation.steampowered.com), but currently the access to store pages is limited and only done by translation admins. Still, the best way to get the error fixed is to contact someone in the correct translation group as they know who can get it fixed even if they cannot do it themselves.